# D3 pie inner label on two lines

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been working with d3pie and I've run into an issue where I cannot get a long inner label to display on a second line.  I can't shorten the text and I need to use inner labels instead of outer labels.

[image]

```
{
    "label": "Treatment & Research",
    "value": 100,
    "color": "#76c4c0"
},
```

Comment: One of two options -- you either set the width via CSS on that `<label>` to have a smaller width so it forces the break or you directly inject HTML into the label as `"Treatment <br/> &amp; Research"`. I am not entirely sure if the second option will work assuming they do escape everything that is passed.

Comment: I tried to directly inject the HTML into the label but it just displayed the tags in the label.  I'll give CSS a shot.

Comment: It doesn't look like injecting CSS works either.  Perhaps I could be doing it wrong, what would it look like?

Comment: Have you tried adding \n as in "Treatment \n & Research" ?